# Pc load: Subprocess vs. Qrunnable vs Qthread

Tags: python, multithreading, qt

I am programming a user interface for some machine in QT+Python. I came to the point that I have to use a couple of parallel processes in order to "talk" to other instruments. A Qtimer would be a bad idea, as the communication and some ongoing measurement can take bit. What's usually done is very simple, I give some start orders, the thread runs and send me the results after some time as a signal.

So far, I used mostly the Qrunnable for this purpose. I realized recently that the number of processes is high and it sums up to a quite significant amount of load to the pc...

I am now wondering, if the subprocess module of python could help to reduce the load. I know that creating the subprocess takes some milliseconds more the Qrunnable, but how is it with the overall load of the machine? Is here somebody experienced with that.

I would like to have a rough idea, before changing everything, as I have to change a couple of things to test that (from signal to stream checking)

Further, I thought Qthread is not needed, as I don't need to "interact" with the tread pool because I am just waiting for results. I expect, but don't know, that there will be no significant difference in Qrunnable and Qthread in sense of performance ... Am I right?

Thanks in advance and best regards ...

Comment: Did you read [ask] and [mcve]?

Comment: well, a minimal example is useless in my opinion as I have just a couple of threads. So its more a question of "what to use" instead of "how to do". And as explained, there is no certain interaction between main prog and threads because any thread is started just for one task, after delivering the results it is finished and stopped.